# Jenkins - Git fetch fails on Windows as service, succeeds from command line

Tags: git, jenkins

I installed Jenkins and got everything working from a command line, then switched it to a Service.

Now the git that was working fine will not load. It hangs on the command

```
git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
git.exe fetch --tags --progress
```

and eventually times out after 10 minutes

```
C:>git version
git version 2.10.2.windows.1
```

I have read several posts that seem to be close to what I am experiencing, but nothing is exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service uses by default the System Account.

Launch `services.msc`, and enter your username/password in the Login tab, in order for that service to run with your account, and to benefit from your Git global settings and credentials.

Comment: Winner, winner, chicken dinner. I thought I had tried this earlier, but this time I set the service, and completely restarted my machine and it is working as expected. Thanks VonC